# Disable additional jars for the maven-shade-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I am using the maven-shade-plugin to create a single executable jar.
I would expect the plugin to create a single jar (`foo.jar`) in the target directory.
However it will also create two other jars: `original-foo.jar` and `foo-shaded.jar`.

Why does it create those files and how do I disable this behavior?

(We have another project using that plugin, where those files are not created. Therefore I am pretty sure it is possible to disable those, but I could not see the difference.)

Answer (score 5):

The plugin maven-shade-plugin by using outputFile is bypasing other behaviours:

```
 <plugin>

      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>

      ...

      <configuration>
           <outputFile>/tmp/watchdog.jar</outputFile>
      </configuration>

 </plugin>
```

More info in: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#outputFile

Comment: An annoying problem is that you can't use `target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar`.

Comment: maven package shows "Error creating shaded jar: error in opening zip XXX" due to the output jar is corrupt

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look into the [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html) documentation which will give you an the option `shadedArtifactAttached` which will control the behaviour your are describing.

```xml
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: This helped to get rid of the `foo-shaded.jar` file, but the `original-foo.jar` file is still generated. I'm also curious why the other project does not generate the `foo-shaded.jar` despite missing the above configuration.

Comment: This didn't remove any of the jars for me.